# Django exception: AppRegistryNotReady Models aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.7 and I want to do some data analysis on my data, so I'm using the ORM to get at it. I've written the following script to retrieve some data:

```
from models import PricePaid
pp = PricePaid.objects.filter(transfer_date__year='1997')
```

But I'm getting this error when I run it:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

I can run `manage.py` without any trouble.

I've tried adding this at the start of the script:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

as suggested by some answers on SO, but then I get a RuntimeError about conflicting models.

What should I do in order to retrieve my data?

Comment: After more googling, it looks like I definitely do need `import django` at the start of the script... So what's the correct import statement to access my models?

Comment: Got it: I had to do `import django`, `django.setup()` and then `from myapp.models import PricePaid`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to write custom scripts and without manually setup django environment is by using [Django's management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/)